# If statement in clause where

Tags: sql, oracle

I need add a where clause only if a condition is respected, for example :

```
SELECT * FROM car Where <a condition> 
and ( if (car.brand = 'Renault') then car.color = 'red')
```

In my example : if the brand is renault i want only red cars and I want other car only if there isn't renault

Is it possible to write something like this in SQL (without PLSQL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an `if` in a `where` clause (SQL doesn't even know `if`). To achieve what you want you need to use something like:

```
where ... and (car.brand = 'Renault' and car.color = 'red' or car.brand <> 'Renault')
```

This disjunction says *"if the brand is Renault, then the color needs to be red, for other brand it doesn't matter"*.

If you - as you comment - *" want only renault red, ... other car only if there isn't renault"*, then you need check for non-existence of renault:

```
where ... 
and (car.brand = 'Renault' and car.color = 'red' 
     or not exists (select * from car where car.brand = 'Renault'))
```

Comment: Thanks but in case when this condition is respected : car.brand = 'Renault' and car.color = 'red', i want only renault red, how can i do this ? i want other car only if there isn't renault

Comment: That is an entirely different case, you should update your question to specifically include that bit because it stands that is not what you are asking. I have added an example that address this question.

Answer (score 1):

Simple logic below.

You might want to write a truth table for any query like this if you are not sure.

```
SELECT * 
FROM car 
WHERE <a condition> 
AND ((car.brand= 'Renault' and car.color = 'red') OR car.brand != 'Renault')
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, i threw it together in a spare minute.

Comment: No problem, I fixed it in the question, so I also fixed it in all the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM car Where <a condition> 
and (car.brand = 'Renault' AND car.color = 'red' OR car.brand <> 'Renault')
```